# Screenshot of directX app without window

Tags: directx, screenshot

I'm running DirectX application on the server (Windows Server 2003) and it does not have window (normally, running on PC, it has window). The issue is that I want to take screenshot of it from it (and save it to the png picture). When running on PC, this is working:

```
Surface backBuff = Device.GetBackBuffer(0, 0, BackBufferType.Mono);
SurfaceLoader.Save(fileName, ImageFileFormat.Png, backBuff);
```

But on server, the only thing I'm given is black picture (with right size).

Is it possible to take screenshot of directX app without window?

Thank you very much for answers

Comment: Are you sue the back buffer is even created without a window?  AFAIK DirectX needs a window to initialise the device ... The window doesn't have to be visible on screen though ... you could always use an off-screen window ...

Comment: Thanks. I hope off-screen rendering will be the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple: running the app from script that is running under another user than IIS.